# Laravel, abstraction layer for 'users' table

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laravel project I want to use the Laravel authentication table 'users' to have a foreign field key to point to another table as layer of abstraction. Is there a way of forcing the user registration to add a row to that abstraction layer table? Its model is simple there is just one attribute.

My RegisterController:
`    protected function create(array $data) {

```
    Rekvirent::create([
        'rekvirent' => $data['initialer'],
    ]);

    return User::create([
        'initialer' => $data['initialer'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

`
I get an error message from mysql that theres a foreign key error suggesting that the rekvirent has not been inserted when it gets to inserting the row in the users table.

My rekvirent model is as follows

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rekvirent extends Model {
    public $timestamps = false;     // dumps timestamps from table
    public $incrementing = false;   // if no autoincrementing
    protected $table = 'rekvirent';    // change default snake-case name
    protected $keyType = 'string';  // if key is not integer

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'initialer',
    ];
/*
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
 */
}
```

Comment: What 'abstraction' are you talking about and why do you need it?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: the abstraction is necessary for transforming two classes into one in a reservation system. The registered users are one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do certain actions once a new user is registered, you can listen to events.

If you see `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php` :

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

You will notice laravel is internally emitting an event `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered`. You can listen to that event and then do actions you need like inserting into a separate table etc.

See event [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#defining-listeners) for listening an event.

Comment: I am looking for a way to insert before the user is inserted

Comment: You can add  that inside `RegisterController`'s  `create()` method before user is actually created for registration.

Comment: Thnx. If you look at the code I added this is exactly what I try to do

Comment: Solved! I had an error in the fillable field name. Change it and everything works. thnx to Mihir for taking an interest in spite of my being a noob here